# Dynamically adding a parameter to socket initialization in ngx-socket-io

Tags: angular, socket.io, ngx-socket-io

I use `ngx-socket-io` package to implement sockets.

For some implementation reasons, I use a lot of namespaces and need to pass the data parameter from a component to the site build.

I tried to use `socket.of(namespace: string`) but I can't add options parameter.

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersListUpdateSocketService extends Socket {

  userListsUpdate$ = this.fromEvent<user[]>('update-users');

  constructor() {
    super({
      url: `${environment.socketUrl}/${SocketEnum.USER_LIST}`,
      options: { data: { parameter: 'value' } }
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is:
I would like, from components, change `{ data: { parameter: 'value' } }` to `{ data: { parameter: 'value2' } }` etc.

Comment: Can you elaborate. What is `data` parameter in option I cannot find it in the docs? It seems like you need to instantiate new sockets to change their options.

Answer (score -1):

if chat is your namespace, then you need to supply it in the url of configuration like this:

```
const config: SocketIoConfig = {url: 'http://localhost:8080/chat', options: {}};
```

or

```
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:8080', options: { path: /chat'' } };
```

but below ex awesome:

```
import { Socket, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';
export class SocketNameSpace extends Socket{
  constructor(socketConfig: SocketIoConfig){
    super(socketConfig);
  }
}

@Component(........) // metadata goes here
export class MyComponent{
    chat: SocketNameSpace;
    news: SocketNameSpace;

    constructor(private socket: Socket){
        // this.socket is for root
        this.chat  = new SocketNameSpace({url: 'http://localhost:3000/chat',options: {} });
        this.news  = new SocketNameSpace({url: 'http://localhost:3000/news',options: {} });
   }
}
```

Comment: I know that, but I would like using generic way solution, one generic service and inject variables. In that question is not important namespace, socket io. etc.